# Size and printout the list of the dropdown items

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to find the length of the dropdown box in Amazons Departments drop down box.  So far I have code for the length of the dropdown box but it just gives the number 1.  I do not know how to print out the rest of the items in the dropdown box.  Here is my code so far:

```
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-line-2' and contains(.,'Departments')]"));
    Thread.sleep(300);
    actions.moveToElement(ele);
    actions.perform();

    //Select dropDown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[4]/a")));
    List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-line-2' and contains(.,'Departments')]"));
    int itemsCount = e.size();
    System.out.println(itemsCount);
        for(WebElement element: e){
        System.out.println(ele.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are locating the `Departments` again, but the items are under another element

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements();
```

You can also add some wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-flyout-shopAll']/div[contains(@class, 'nav-tpl-itemList')]/a"));
```

Comment: How did you get the locator?

Comment: @squathub I opened the dropdown -> right click ->Inspect.

Comment: did you use fire path? and did you inspect the first item not the Departments

Comment: @squathub No, I'm using chrome. But same idea.

Comment: Guy can't for there life of me how you got that locator sorry I am a newbie

Comment: @squathub Right click on the opened dropdown abd select `inspect` (might be different name in FF). This will lead you to the element location in the html in the developer tools. This will probably be one of the list items, but this is the location, you just need to look at the parent element(s).